# Why might ReadToEnd throw an OutOfMemory exception but ReadAllText doesn't?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, out-of-memory

I'm running into an issue where ReadToEnd is throwing an OutOfMemory exception when trying to read a 16MB text file in an ASP.net website.

While investigating the cause I came across File.ReadAllText which is really what I'm doing, I don't care about how I get the text.

But looking at the documentation of [ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=VS.90).aspx) it doesn't mention the possibility of an OutOfMemory exception. Why is that? Is it implemented differently than ReadToEnd in such a way that its less likely to run out of memory, or does it throw some other exception if it runs out of memory?

**Edit** Adding code just to show what I'm currently doing:

```
StreamReader inputFile = System.IO.File.OpenText(filename);
string cacheData = inputFile.ReadToEnd();
inputFile.Close();
```

And sometimes I get OutOfMemory exception on line 2. No parsing going on, the file is only 16M of text, nothing strange that I know of.

Restarting IIS generally fixes it. But I have like 2G of RAM free when I get the error, IIS maybe hitting some internal limit? The w3wp.exe process usually uses 350-500M (This is IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003)

Comment: A lot of code can throw OutOfMemoryException, not just ReadAllText...

Comment: @minitech: Why? This isn't a question about his code.

Comment: gasp... could it be possible that not all exceptions are documented?

Comment: @spender: I just want to see if he's doing it incorrectly; reading a 16MB file shouldn't cause a computer to become out of memory, usually.

Comment: Added my code and a bit more context of the problem, but that's more of a question for ServerFault I'd think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Reflector, System.IO.File class:

```
public static string ReadAllText(string path, Encoding encoding)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Just like that.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but just to summarize this answer: both will throw or not throw exceptions identically, given identical parameters.

Comment: But this doesn’t explain why `ReadToEnd()` will randomly throw exceptions when the OS itself does not seem to be under memory pressure…

Comment: @binki plenty of possible reasons - memory fragmentation, huge file, 32-bit IIS as question author points out below... it all depends on context. The question was, how is it possible that `ReadToEnd()` throws an exception while `ReadAllText()` does't. This explains that it is only a coincidence because `ReadAllText()` calls `ReadToEnd()` hence if latter thrown an exception - it would be propagated out of the former as well.

Comment: @IvanDanilov, looking back at this and re-reading the question and the OP’s posted code, perhaps the difference is that `ReadAllText()` correctly calls `StreamReader.Dispose()` while the OP’s code doesn’t show that happening. The docs of `StreamReader` suggest that it holds its own buffers, which I imagine might end up using generous amounts of memory. Unfortunately this is just speculation and this question is old, sorry xD.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with a C# Windows Forms Application. Building my application with the target platform set to 64 bit solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadAllText` throws an OutOfMemory exception if you attempt to read a file that contains too much text to fit into memory - have just tried it.

Comment: The OutOfMemory exception from ReadToEnd happens so infrequently that I'm not able to re-create it in my code yet. The question is more about why one documents OutOfMemory as a possible exception but the other doesn't, are they implemented similarly (does ReadAllText call ReadToEnd?)

Comment: @thelsdj - as Tomas states above, a lot of calls can generate an `OutOfMemoryException`.  MS probably decided against documenting each and every case where this can occur.

Comment: @thelsdj: documentation is, believe it or not, sometimes wrong or incomplete.

Comment: In fact OutOfMemoryException could be thrown potentially absolutely from any line of your code. Probably except rare guarded regions (like finally blocks). For example when JIT-compiler tries to process your method - it could go out of memory. You just can't predict it.

Comment: this is very true!

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://jesperen.wordpress.com/2007/12/10/aspnet-memory-limit/) does a good job of explaining why I was having the original OutOfMemory error. IIS 6.0 on 32 bit Windows Server 2003 could only use about 600-700M of memory, even though I had 4GB.

Adding /3GB to boot.ini and rebooting the server made the error go away (even though my IIS memory usage doesn't appear to go much above what it originally was).